# open the hyperlink from datatable in vbscripy:qtp

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Is there any way in which we can extract  links from global table and use it in script to open it up.That means we have to open a hyperlinks which are  in datatable .
eg in this line 
Browser("Browser").Page("KOHLER_4").Link("Reports").Click

we can take link "report" from datatable and then run the script

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 Browser("Browser").Navigate DataTable("URL", dtGlobalSheet)
```

You use the `DataTable` utility to get the value from the data table, you can use this value as a parameter to a method (as seen above) or as part of an object's description, e.g:

```
Link("href:="& DataTable("URL", dtGlobalSheet))
```